# Access blocked on my HDD

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

These are the messages that come up if I want to delete or create a new folder on that drive.

[image: Destination Folder Access Denied]

It is a secondary drive and has NO FILES at all.

So far I have changed permissions, made myself the owner, icacls reset, chkdisk, sfc scan, error checking that repaired the drive when I restarted, multiple virus scans and the last thing I did was FORMAT my drive.

None of them worked.

I am thinking of just factory resetting at this point and hoping it will work, but is there anything else anyone thinks I could do that won't make me lose all my primary drives data?

I use a laptop, windows 8.1, the primary drive that has my OS is an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've OS in your SSD and there is no data present in your HDD I'd try the below method first.

- Open Command Prompt in elevated mode. (Press `Start` type `cmd` `right click` on search result and `Run as administrator`.
- Press `Yes` when it shows the UAC dialogue box.
- Type `diskpart` in command prompt and press `enter`.
- Now type `List disk` and press `enter`.
- Note down which one is your HDD drive and type `Select disk 2` (Change the number according to your HDD number shown from the last command.
- Now type `clean` and press `enter`. (Be careful this one deletes all data so make sure you've choosen right disk in `select disk` command.)
- Then `Create Partition Primary` and `enter`.
- `Format fs=ntfs label=YourDesiredLabel` and `enter`.
- `Assign` and `enter`
- `Exit`

Now, check if you have full access to the drive or not. I hope this will work for you.

And if this one still does not help then I doubt there is some problem with your hardware.